# Qt update an image in the UI through callback

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a function `streamCamera(*callback)` where the callback is `void callback(Image)` which can be used to preview the stream in any UI framework we want.

I was able to stream with this function in a opencv imshow window

```
void callback(image)
{
    cv::imshow("image", image);
    waitKey(1);
}
```

while the imshow is a static function and was able to stream.

**Is there anything similar i can do with Qt?**

---

What I tried,

I have a `class MainWindow` which inherits `QMainWindow`, inside the class i have attached a `QGraphicsPixmapItem pixImage` into the ui with `ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(&pixImage);`

since the `pixImage` is not accessible to the callback function, cause the Mainwindow object is not global. I was not able to set image in the pixmap;

So i ended up doing a hack, just created a global pointer a `QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixImagePtr` and attached the `pixImage` before starting the `streamCamera(*callback)` and inside the callback i use the `pixImagePtr` to set the image GUI, and **it worked**.

But this hack seems like not the right way to do, so it would be helpful if some qt experts shed some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something that should be done with signals.

Let's say you have your `MainWindow` and `Worker` class. 
`Worker` wants to show some image inside the `MainWindow`, you can do it like this.

```cpp
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
Q_OBJECT
// Other members
public slots:
    void showImage(const QPixmap &pixmap) {
        pixImage.setPixmap(pixmap);
    }
};


class Worker : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(MainWindow* parent) : QObject{parent} {
        connect(this, &Worker::pixmapChanged,
                parent, &MainWindow::showImage);
    }

signals:
    void pixmapChanged(QPixmap pixmap);
}
```

From now inside `Worker` you should be able to use `pixmapChanged` signal to change `MainWindow` image like so.

```cpp
const QPixmap pixmap = getNewPixmap();
emit pixmapChanged(pixmap);
```